# When testing my windows store app it says my PC supports touch when it shouldn't

Tags: c#, windows-8, touch

I'm on a PC with no touch enabled monitor, however the below is evaluated to true:

```
new Windows.Devices.Input.TouchCapabilities().TouchPresent != 0
```

Why is this?

Will it be reliable once my app is published?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've realised that although I had visual studio set to debug it on the local machine, I had the simulator still running from earlier testing.

It seems if you have the simulator (that is touch enabled) it'll report that your local machine is touch enabled even if it isn't!

Comment: Well, you *are* simulating a touch-capable device.

Comment: I'd have thought it wouldn't take that into account when running/debugging on the local machine. I'd expect the simulator to be self-contained and not leak out into the host machine. Still, it's a simple fix!

Comment: On my system it looks like system thinks that touch screen exists even when no simulator is launched. So I had to launch app in simulator (to run it) and then close its window. Then system says that yes, there's no touch caps.